# jquery Tabs с обработкой hash-tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

```
    initTabs();

    function initTabs(){
        $('.tabset ul.tab-list li a').on('click', function(){
            var thisHold = $(this).closest(".tabset");
            var _ind = $(this).closest('li').index();
            thisHold.children('.tab-holder').children(".tab").removeClass('active');
            thisHold.children('.tab-holder').children("div.tab:eq("+_ind+")").addClass('active');
            $(this).closest("ul").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            return false;
        });
    }

                        <div id="tabset" class="tabset">
                            <ul class="tab-list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab1">link Tab1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab2">link Tab2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#tab3">link Tab3</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-holder">
                            <div class="tab active">
                                Text Tab1
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab">
                                Text Tab2
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab">
                                Text Tab3
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Помогите сделать функцию обработчик hashtag чтобы при вызове страницы site.ru/page#tab2 становился активным нужный таб

Comment: css не хватает.

Comment: извлекать из location хеш и и сделать активной вкладку по этому хешу.

Comment: css для примера не нужен, логика и так понятна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, но дописать проще уже имея в руках все карты.
Итак, табы написанные [димоксом](http://dimox.name/universal-jquery-tabs-script/).
Дописал все то, что после комментария в js. Это банальный пример, можно все это организовать на cookies или другим способом.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {margin: 30px; font: 13px/1.5 "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial;}
a {color: #0094D6;}
p {padding: 7px 0;}
h1 {font-size: 21px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0 0 30px;}

.tabs {
 width: 600px;
 background: #EFEFEF;
 margin: 0 0 30px;
}
.tabs__caption {
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 25px;
 list-style: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
 background: #FFF;
}
.tabs__caption li {
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 1px -1px 0;
 padding: 0 13px 1px;
 color: #777;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #F9F9F9;
 border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #F9F9F9;
 position: relative;
}
.tabs__caption li:hover,
.vertical .tabs__caption li:hover {
 color: #F70;
 padding: 0 13px;
 background: #FFFFDF;
 border: 1px solid #FFCA95;
}
.tabs__caption .active {
 color: #444;
 background: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 0 13px 2px;
 border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
}
.tabs__content {
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
 border-width: 0 1px 1px;
 background: #EFEFEF;
 padding: 0 12px;
}
.tabs__content.active {
 display: block;
}

.tabs.vertical {
 width: 440px;
 border-left: 160px solid #FFF;
}
.vertical .tabs__caption {
 width: 160px;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 0 0 -160px;
}
.vertical .tabs__caption li {
 padding: 0 13px;
 margin: 0 0 1px;
 border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
 border-right: 1px solid #F9F9F9;
 width: 132px;
 height: 25px;
}
.vertical .tabs__caption li:hover {
 width: 131px;
}
.vertical .tabs__caption .active {
 width: 133px;
 color: #444;
 background: #EFEFEF;
 border: 1px solid #D4D4D4;
 border-right: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
 margin-right: -1px;
}
.vertical .tabs__content {
 border-width: 1px;
}
</style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
    //дописал отсюда
    var hash = location.hash;
    if ( hash !== '') {
     console.log('hash ' + hash);
     var i = $('ul.tabs__caption li').has('a[href*=' + hash + ']').index();
     console.log('i ' + i);
     $('ul.tabs__caption li').has('a[href*=' + hash + ']').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
     .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
    //дописал досюдава

    $('ul.tabs__caption').on('click', 'li:not(.active) a', function() {
       $(this).parent()
         .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
         .closest('div.tabs').find('div.tabs__content').removeClass('active').eq($(this).parent().index()).addClass('active');
     });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tabs">

  <ul class="tabs__caption">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">1-я вкладка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">2-я вкладка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3">3-я вкладка</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tabs__content active">
    Деонтология создает примитивный даосизм, открывая новые горизонты. Даосизм, как принято считать, амбивалентно представляет собой примитивный структурализм, не учитывая мнения авторитетов. Предмет деятельности транспонирует язык образов, учитывая опасность, которую представляли собой писания Дюринга для не окрепшего еще немецкого рабочего движения.
  </div>

  <div class="tabs__content">
    Даосизм, по определению, создает здравый смысл, учитывая опасность, которую представляли собой писания Дюринга для не окрепшего еще немецкого рабочего движения. Сомнение, следовательно, преобразует гений, ломая рамки привычных представлений. Сомнение трогательно наивно.
  </div>

   <div class="tabs__content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Да, то что надо. Можно показать еще пример где задается класс active в меню не для списка а для ссылки, т.е. 
 <li><a href="#tab1" class="active">1-я вкладка</a></li>